# How to change the dashlet name in alfresco community v5.0.0?

Tags: custom-controls, alfresco-share, dashlet

I am unable to change the dashlet title names. In the customize dashboard page there is an option to only choose among the predefined dashlets. How do we add a custom dashlet or change the name of the dashlets available.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to do it.

We need to change the header in the property files under the folder '\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\dashlets\'

for ex: to change the title of the image preview dashlet, we need to change the header in imagesummary.get.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change Name of dashlet directly without changing code.If you want to change name of existing dashlet you need to override that dashlet.

For creating new dashlet I have have some references which are as below.

http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/concepts/kb-dashlet.html
http://customizealfresco.blogspot.in/2012/09/create-simple-dashlet-in-alfresco-share.html
https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Custom_Dashlets